# Multiplication become float and convert to int become negative in php 5.5

Tags: php

I don't know if it related to server (IIS with apache and php 5.5) but this function to return bytes give me negative result when set as **2048M**

It return **-2147483648** !!!!!!!

```
function return_bytes_2($val) {

    if(empty($val))return 0;

    $val = trim($val);

    preg_match('#([0-9]+)[\s]*([a-z]+)#i', $val, $matches);

    $last = '';
    if(isset($matches[2])){
        $last = $matches[2];
    }

    if(isset($matches[1])){
        $val = (int) $matches[1];
    }

    var_dump($val);

    switch (strtolower($last))
    {
        case 'g':
        case 'gb':
            $val *= 1024;
            var_dump($val); // output int(2048)
        case 'm':
        case 'mb':
            $val *= 1024;
            var_dump($val); // output int(2097152)
        case 'k':
        case 'kb':
            $val *= 1024;
            var_dump($val); // output float(2147483648) <--- become float
    }

    return (int)$val; // it return with negative sign!!!!

}




$memory_limit = return_bytes_2(ini_get('memory_limit')); // 2048M on my server

var_dump($memory_limit); // output: int(-2147483648) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WHY!!!!!!

var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit')); // output: string(5) "2048M"
```

I can't replicate it on other server or using phptester website :( any suggest?

Comment: Perhaps it's a 32-bit server? 2048M would overflow a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: @Nick yes it is installed apache in 32 bit version

Comment: Well that's your answer then. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php): If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.

Comment: @Nick thank you. so i can simply remove casting. Or is better to do other condiseration? thanks

Comment: Removing casting will resolve this problem but potentially lead to floating point precision issues (although it should be fine in most use cases for this code). Ideally you should stop using the 32-bit server and migrate all your work to 64-bit machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing an integer overflow.

This is due to the binary representation of signed integers.

To go from a positive number to its negative value (or the opposite), read from right to left the bits until the first **1**, then, invert each remaining bits.

The bit that is the most on the left (called the Most Significant Bit, or the MSB)  defines the sign. `1` for negative, `0` for positive

In example, 42 in (16 bits) binary is

```
0000 0000 0010 1010
```

Reading from right to left until the first **1** splits the binary word into this :

```
0000 0000 0010 10 *10*
```

Then, inverting the remaining bits gives this binary word :

```
1111 1111 1101 0110
```

Which is -42

The biggest **32 bits** signed integer is, in binary representation

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

That corresponds in `2147483647`

Adding 1 gives :

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

This number being 2^31, `2147483648`, but since the MSB is 1, it's evaluated as a negative number, `-2147483648`